# Add array column to DB using Devise

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add an extra field "favourites' to my database, obviously favourites should be an array of Int (ID of the event to add as favourite).
How can I generate a migration for that?

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this in your migration

> add_column :users, :favourites, :integer, array: true, default: []

probably better rename column to favourites_ids

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
rails g migration AddFavouritesToUser favourites:text
```

Then modify the migration before you run it...

```
add_column :users, :favourites, :text, array: true, default: []
```